# Buttons and text flickering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I copied most of this code from an earlier script which worked fine, but when I load up the game, pretty much all the elements  are flickering.
Here is the Minimal complete verifiable example here:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 1280
displayHeight = 720

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Grow')

black = (0, 0, 0)
brown = (100, 100, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
lightGreen = (0, 255, 0)
red = (200, 0, 0)
lightRed = (255, 0, 0)

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

def gameIntro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(brown)
        message_to_screen('Welcome to Tanks', green, -100, 'large')
        message_to_screen('The objective is to shoot and destroy', black, -30)
        message_to_screen('Shoot and destroy the enemy tank before they destroy you', black, 10)
        message_to_screen('The more enemies you destroy, the harder they get', black, 50)

        button('quit', 500, 500, 100, 50, red, lightRed, action = 'quit')
        button('play', 200, 500, 100, 50, green, lightGreen, action = 'play')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(0)

def gameLoop():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def button(text, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x, y, width, height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if action == 'play':
                gameLoop()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color, (x, y, width, height))
    text_to_button(text, black, x, y, width, height)

def text_to_button(msg, colour, buttonx, buttony, buttonwidth, buttonheight, size = 'small'):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects (msg, colour, size)
    textRect.center = ((buttonx + (buttonwidth/2)), buttony + (buttonheight/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def message_to_screen(msg, colour, y_displace = 0, size = 'small'):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects (msg, colour, size)
    textRect.center = (displayWidth / 2), (displayHeight / 2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def text_objects(text, colour, size):
    if size == 'small':
        textSurface = smallfont.render (text, True, colour)
    elif size == 'medium':
        textSurface = medfont.render (text, True, colour)
    elif size == 'large':
        textSurface = largefont.render (text, True, colour)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect() 

gameIntro()
```

For some reason, in the gameIntro function, when I call the message_to_screen and button functions, they all start flickering (everything except the first function called). Changing the order of the functions changes which one will stop flickering. Everything else works fine. The buttons change colour when the cursor is above them and they can still be clicked and have functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `pygame.display.update()` multiple times in each iteration of your game loop. It will lead to the screen flickering you see.

Simply remove the `pygame.display.update()` calls in the `message_to_screen` and `text_to_button` functions.